# Collaborate workshared model to cloud (ACC) without opening Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

Is there any method to save/collaborate a model to ACC without opening Revit software (using any API?).

SaveAsCloudModel method is working with Revit software interface while calling through addin. Looking for a solution to do the same without opening Revit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DesignAutomation for Revit** to automate this task. Basically, this runs an instance of Revit in the cloud and allow you to run custom plugins.

This post explains that **DesignAutomation** allows to work with Revit Cloud Models but also that you can create a Revit Cloud Model from DA:

[DesignAutomation API supports Revit Cloud Model](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-api-supports-revit-cloud-model)